# sonar not generating reports with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I have jenkins installed and integrated with sonar but I get the following error during sonar analysis:

```
send-mail: error while loading shared libraries: libmysqlclient.so.16: cannot open     shared object file: No such file or directory
[workspace] $ mvn -f /root/.jenkins/jobs/test_4.9/workspace/pom.xml -e -B sonar:sonar -Dsonar.jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.xx:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true -Dsonar.host.url=http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/sonar
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mvn" (in directory "/root/.jenkins/jobs/test/workspace"): error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:709)
at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:338)
at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:345)
at hudson.tasks.Maven.perform(Maven.java:263)
at hudson.plugins.sonar.utils.SonarMaven.executeMaven(SonarMaven.java:138)
at hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarPublisher.executeSonar(SonarPublisher.java:300)
at hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarPublisher.perform(SonarPublisher.java:261)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:36)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:710)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:685)
at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.post2(Build.java:162)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.post(AbstractBuild.java:632)
at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1463)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:239)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:135)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1021)
... 18 more
Sonar analysis completed: FAILURE
Build step 'Sonar' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Sonar' marked build as failure
```

Answer (score 2):

Follow the instructions correctly in the [URL](http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=116359341) to make sonar works with jenkins.